# What is the meaning of this math formulation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, network-flow

I have been wondering what is the meaning of this sigma with delta negative or plus in there (if my read is correct).

$$
\sum_{i \in \Delta^{-}(j)} x_{i j k}-\sum_{i \in \Delta^{+}(j)} x_{j i k}=0 \quad \forall k \in K, j \in N
$$

Comment: That doesn't look like anything standard. it is probably (or should be) explained in the paper or book in which it appears.  The delta negative and delta positive presumably describe sets of i which are members of that set for the specified j.

Comment: yeah sure it was from the paper. What is the different between the negative and plus one?

Comment: I don't know.. I don't even know what the paper is - you haven't told us.. Presumably, the paper explains that.

Comment: the paper is this https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9648591

Comment: I don't have access to that paper.

Comment: I'm just guessing since the paper doesn't define it, but maybe it's related to [indegree and outdegree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree) and means the vertices pointed at by something and pointing to something.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a standard flow conservation constraint. In network models, it is somewhat common to use either $\Delta^-(v)$ or $\delta^-(v)$ to denote the set of nodes $u$ for which there is an arc from $u$ to $v$, and $\Delta^+(v)$ or $\delta^+(v)$ to denote the set of nodes $u$ for which there is an arc from $v$ to $u.$ So the constraint may be saying that for every node $j$ and every commodity / vehicle type / whatever $k,$ the flow of $k$ entering $j$ equals the flow of $k$ exiting $j.$